# Algorithm i can not solve, but why?

Tags: algorithm

It's my very 1st time doing algorithm.
Can someone help me solve the 2 followings?:

```
A <- [3, 3, 0]
While A[2] < A[1] :
    A[0] <- A[0] + A[0]
    A[2] <- A[2] + 1
Show A[0] + A[2]
```

And

```
> A <- 4
B <- 7
If B < 5 :
    Show A - B
Else :
    Show 2*B
```

Thanks!

Comment: what programming language is this? or is it just pseudocode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like homework, instead of giving the exact solution, I will give you some clues:

- A <- 4: Find out what it means, probably A will get assigned the value of 4.
- B <- 7: Similar for above.
- The IF statement compares the two values, find out which is true, if true, the line Show A - B is executed, ELSE (thus if the condition in the IF is false), the second statement (Show 2*B) is executed.

For the while loop, make a table with A[0], A[1] and A[2], and every time the value changes, write the new value in the column (so keep track of the values of A[0] to A[2]). A While loop continues while the condition is true. When the condition is false, the statement continues after the While (thus Show A[0] + A[2].